# Custom user registration shortcode - redirect header issue

Tags: shortcode, user-registration

I've created a custom shortcode that calls a function which will produce a registration page.

Registration works. No issue here.

The issue I am having is to log the user in after a successful registration.

I understand the reason I am getting `header already sent error` is because the shortcode is loaded after the header information.

What is the best way to redirect or log the user in within a shortcode

`add_action( 'user_register', array($this,'auto_login_new_user'), 10);`

```
function auto_login_new_user( $user_id ) {
    // exit($user_id);
    wp_set_current_user($user_id);
    wp_set_auth_cookie($user_id);

    wp_redirect( home_url() );
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to rely on javascript for the redirect. You can set it like this in your shortcode.

```
 $html = "<script>
              location.href = " . $home_url() . "
          </script>";
 return $html;
```

It will load the page and then redirect immediately.

Comment: @user742736 You can log in a user with `wp_set_auth_cookie()`, but it has to be before headers are sent. So, in this case you can't. Why don't you redirect them to the Login page instead?

Comment: Yeah looks like I will need to use JS to redirect them to the log in page